# Diagnosing root cause long HTTP response turnaround in Golang

Tags: http, go, timeout

So my HTTP client initialisation and send request code looks like this.

```golang
package http_util

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var httpClient *http.Client

func Init() {
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig:     &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 200,
        IdleConnTimeout:     90 * time.Second,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }
    httpClient = &http.Client{Transport: tr, Timeout: 30 * time.Second}
}

func SendRequest(ctx context.Context, request *http.Request) (*SomeRespStruct, error) {
    httpResponse, err := httpClient.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    responseBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(httpResponse.Body)
    defer httpResponse.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    response := &SomeRespStruct{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(responseBody, response)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return response, nil
}
```

When I launch my server, I call `http_util.Init()`.

The issue arises when I receive multiple requests (20+) at once to call this external server. In one of my functions I do

```golang
package external_api

import (
    "context"
    "log"
)

func SomeAPICall(ctx context.Context) (SomeRespStruct, error) {
    // Build request
    request := buildHTTPRequest(...)
    log.Printf("Send request: %v", request)
    response, err := http_util.SendRequest(ctx, request)
    // Error checks
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("HTTP request timed out: %v", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    log.Printf("Received response: %v", response)
    return response, nil
}
```

My issue is that I get a 15~20s lag in between the `Send request` and `Received response` logs based on the output timestamp *when there is high request volume*. Upon checking with the server that's handling my requests, I found out that on their end, processing time from end-to-end takes less than a second (the same exact request that had a long turnaround time according to my own logs), so I'm not too sure what is the root cause of this high turnaround time. I also did a `traceroute` and a `ping` to the server as well and there was no delay, so this should not be a network error.

I've looked around and it seems like the suggested solutions are:

1. to increase the `MaxIdleConnsPerHost`
2. to read the HTTP response body in full and close it

Both of which I have already done.

I'm not sure if there is more tuning to be done regarding the configuration of my HTTP client to  resolve this issue, or if I should investigate other workarounds, for instance retry or perhaps scaling (but my CPU and memory utilisation are at the 2-3% range).

Comment: 1. How much data is being processed by the `ioutil.ReadAll` call?
2. Have you tried benchmarking the server before address the client issue?

Comment: You can try to use https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/ in order to find metrics that can be helpful